# What is the proper syntax for: WHERE strIng CONTAINS strSearch

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

Normally, I'd set a "Contains" filter on my string field, and enter my value in the modal box, but I want to audit the process.

```
UPDATE Data SET Data.[Assumed Expires]=Data.[Assumed Expires]+365 WHERE Data.[Description]=strSearch;
```

Thanks a pile!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't remember Access syntax exactly, but something like this to do a substring match:

```
WHERE Data.[Description] like '*' & strSearch & '*';
```

Comment: The wild card can be % if you are querying through ADO or have set SQL Compatibility (ANSI 92).